# Defining simple paths that could be simple cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently looking into some Graph theory and I am trying to define the set of all simple paths in a graph G = (V,E) that could also be a cycle (the first node is the same as the last node). Could I write this down in a better way and am I missing possible cases?

$$
\begin{aligned}
P = \{v_0,v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_{l} \mid v \in V,  \forall i > 0, j>0 : v_i \neq v_j \Leftrightarrow i\neq j,\\
\forall 1 \leq i \leq l : (v_{i-1},v_{i}) \in E)\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition allows the following sequence of vertices: $u_0, u_1, u_2, u_0, u_3$ that is a cycle with a tail.

> So it would be better to say $\forall i \ge 0 \forall j \ge 0\colon v_i = v_j \iff i = j \lor \{\,i, j\,\} = \{\,0, l\,\}$.

Comment: Forgot about that. Could I also say the following? \begin{aligned}
P = \{v_0,v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_{l} \mid \forall 0 \leq i < j \leq l : 
(v_{i-1},v_{i}) \in E,\\ \forall 0 \leq h < i : v_h = v_i \implies (h,i) = (0,l)  \}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Yes, that's pretty good. However I would use $j$ instead of $i$ in the last line, or write $0 \le h < i \le l$ for the reason of not to be confusing with previous $0 \le i < j \le l$.

Comment: BTW, what is sense of your $j$? Also I guess you meant $(v_i, v_{i + 1}) \in E$.

Comment: you're right, for some reason I copied in the j!